# Why in wx.ComboBox wx.EVT_TEXT event is called twice?

Tags: wxpython

In the code, I bind the event `self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnText)` to wx.ComboBox.
The `OnText` is called twice. I saw similar behavior with other events too.

My question is:

- Is it an expected behavior?
- If yes, how is the correct way to handle
  them?

I saw the following solution:

```
def OnText(self, event):
    if self.event_skip:
        self.event_skip = False
        return
    do_somthing()
    self.event_skip = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably, the answer to your 1st question is Yes!
You are binding to `wx.EVT_TEXT` rather than the more usual `wx.EVT_COMBOBOX`, the result I would expect would be an event triggered for each and every text event within that combobox, such as typing or cancelling characters in it.
I suspect, that what you actually want is `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` which emits an event only when you press the enter key, which would allow you to input a choice not in the `choices`. To do that you need to have created the combobox with the `style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER` option.
The events for a combobox are:

```
EVT_COMBOBOX: Process a wxEVT_COMBOBOX event, when an item on the list is selected. Note that calling GetValue returns the new value of selection.
EVT_TEXT: Process a wxEVT_TEXT event, when the combobox text changes.
EVT_TEXT_ENTER: Process a wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER event, when RETURN is pressed in the combobox (notice that the combobox must have been created with wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER style to receive this event).
EVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN: Process a wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN event, which is generated when the list box part of the combo box is shown (drops down). Notice that this event is only supported by wxMSW, wxGTK with GTK+ 2.10 or later, and OSX/Cocoa.
EVT_COMBOBOX_CLOSEUP: Process a wxEVT_COMBOBOX_CLOSEUP event, which is generated when the list box of the combo box disappears (closes up). This event is only generated for the same platforms as wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN above. Also note that only wxMSW and OSX/Cocoa support adding or deleting items in this event.
```

Edit:
I had a look at the code you referenced in a comment to the other answer. It is slightly confusing because it refers to `self.ignoreEvtText`, which make it look as if it is in some way related to either the `event` or `EVT_TEXT`.
It isn't! The coder set that variable up themselves,

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.EvtText)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.EvtChar)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.EvtCombobox)
self.ignoreEvtText = False
```

and is using it to manipulate what happens because they bound 3 events to the same combobox.
If the user selects an item from choices `wx.EVT_COMBOBOX` or if the user presses `back tab` (keycode 8) `wx.EVT_CHAR`, the `wx.EVT_TEXT` events are ignored.
I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I realized that when catching this event and manipulating the text in it for autocomplete, the text manipulation can trigger the second event. Am I right? Did you mean that? In the first part of your answer I did not completely understand what you meant by saying yes for 1st question? Somehow I created this question because I had experience with double events for example aui.EVT_AUI_PERSPECTIVE_CHANGED event when docking. But I think I should create another question for this question as it is out of the scope.

Comment: Your 1st question in this post, was "Is it an expected behaviour?" It was to that, that I was responding. Later I realised that you had posted an example in your response to the other answer, to which I responded in my edit. I was referring to the triggering of possibly multiple events because of text manipulation, as you put it, after binding to `wx.EVT_TEXT`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that getting two events is the expected behavior. I constructed a minimal working example of a wx.TextCtrl, and whatever I tried, a single change of the content of this control fired up only one wx.EVT_TEXT event for me, not two:

```
import time
import wx

def evthandler(evt):
    print(time.time())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    text = wx.TextCtrl(frame)
    text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, evthandler)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Here is an example what I mean: for wx.Combobox  not wx.TextCtrl. https://wiki.wxpython.org/Combo%20Box%20that%20Suggests%20Options